# Replace anchor with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, anchor

I am trying to `activate/deactivate` user by clicking on anchor. The list of users is generated dynamically from the loop. Following is one example of anchor tag.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/users/deactivate/44" class="btn btn-success" title="Deactivate">Activated</a>
```

The `ajax call/database updates/response` are working fine. What I want is to change the above anchor appropriately with updated `href, class, title and text` on the success. For an example it should now change to

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/users/activate/44" class="btn btn-danger" title="Activate">Inactive</a>
```

I have the following jquery code:

```
$(".btn").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var urlSplit=$(this).attr("href").split("/");
    var userid = urlSplit[urlSplit.length-1];
    var status = urlSplit[urlSplit.length-2];
    var $self = $(this); 

    if(status === 'activate'){
        $.post("users/" + status + "/" + userid, {userid: userid, status: status}, function(response){
            if(response === 'activated'){
                //Edit added code
                $self.text("Activated");
                $self.attr('href', "http://www.example.com/users/deactivate/"+userid);
                $self.attr('class', "btn btn-success");
                $self.attr('title', "Deactivate");
            }
        });

    }

    if(status === 'deactivate'){
        $.post("users/" + status + "/" + userid, {userid: userid, status: status}, function(response){
            if(response === 'deactivated'){
                //Edit added code
                $self.text("Inactive");
                $self.attr('href', "http://www.example.com/users/activate/"+userid);
                $self.attr('class', "btn btn-danger");
                $self.attr('title', "Activate");
            }
        });

    }

});
```

**EDIT:**

I have added the code inside the success response. Though it seems to work fine it does not quite look the right way for me or is it? I have to move the cursor away and focus in again to see the change in `href` and `title`.

Comment: Have you actually got absolute URLs like your example, or are they relative URLs (which is more common)? Rather than using the URL segments, I suggest you inject an `data-` attribute like data-`active="true"`, which is far easier to query and modify.

Comment: I have got the  URLs like they are in my example.

Comment: Use the F12 Chrome debug tools and view the DOM and you will see it changes instantly. Your current browser may not bother to check for updates (to title etc) while the cursor is still over it. That is not unexpected. Chrome works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty straight-forward, unless I have misread the problem. Use string replace and `attr` to change the attributes. Use `removeClass` and `addClass` to change the classes. `$self` already points at the specific link that caused the event.

```
$(".btn").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var urlSplit=$(this).attr("href").split("/");
    var userid = urlSplit[urlSplit.length-1];
    var status = urlSplit[urlSplit.length-2];
    var $self = $(this); 

    if(status === 'activate'){
        $.post("users/" + status + "/" + userid, {userid: userid, status: status}, function(response){
            if(response === 'activated'){
                $self.text("Activated");
                // what to do here
                $self.attr('href', $self.attr('href').replace('activate', 'deactivate'));
                $self.removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-success');
                $self.attr('title', 'Activate');
            }
        });

    }

    if(status === 'deactivate'){
        $.post("users/" + status + "/" + userid, {userid: userid, status: status}, function(response){
            if(response === 'deactivated'){
                //what to do here
                $self.text("Inactive");
                $self.attr('href', $self.attr('href').replace('deactivate', 'activate'));
                $self.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger');
                $self.attr('title', 'Deactivate');
            }
        });

    }
});
```

### Simple mockup: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9gLta/2/

I knocked out the Ajax calls to test it.

**Update: Note the question code was changed after this was posted to include most of this code.**

Comment: The changes are applied instantly on your demo. But I have to refocus my cursor to see the link url and title changes in my system. I am using Chrome.

Comment: That is a browser issue and nothing I know you can do about it. You are after all *pulling out the rug from under the link that you are over*. Latest version of Chrome they reappear after a second (and the status bar link changes instantly) :)

Comment: But it is strange that the demo code works fine on my Chrome but the same code in my project has this issue. I have latest Chrome and even after seconds I don't see the aforementioned changes.

Comment: But your DOM changes when viewed in the F12 DOM explorer? If so that *is* weird.

Comment: The DOM changes instantly everytime. But the title and link the broswer shows changes only sometimes. And the other times, it does not change but after a pause changes twice quickly responding to the two successive clicks. May be the changes are not propagated quick enough. Seems like I cannot do anything about it and is the broswer issue.

Comment: Certainly not the code. The only other suggestion I would add is to use a delegated `on` event to reduce the overhead of your click handlers, but that is trivial.

Comment: I think this is fine enough.